# Compare and Merge two files in R

Tags: r, merge, compare

I have two files

file1:

```
start,end,expr,name

10,20,0.2,A

1,5,0.6,B

23,45,0.8,A

89,98,0.89,C
```

file2:

```
start,end,expr 

18,19,0.6

11,16,0.9

16,18,0.78

1,2,0.23

3,5,0.88
```

I want to compare and merge these two files together. If start and end of file2 locates within start and end of file1, then calculate and incorporate mean and std of file2 data.

For example,

in file2, the first three rows all locates within (10, 20), so calculate mean and std of expr in these three rows, and then put mean and std as the 5th and 6th columns of file1

```
start,end,expr,name, mean(file2), std(file2)

10,20,0.2,A,0.76,0.151

1,5,0.6,B,0.555,0.4596

23,45,0.8,A

89,98,0.89,C
```

Is there anyone know how to achieve my goal by using R? Thank you a lot.
The actual data is much bigger, here is only an example of the data.

Comment: provide a code example of what you've tried so far.

Comment: One more thing is that, the actual data is much bigger, here is only an example. I do appreciate if anyone can help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code example helps

```
file1 <- read.csv('file1.csv',header=TRUE)
file2 <- read.csv('file2.csv',header=TRUE)

for(i in seq(nrow(file1))){
  ## tf defines the subset of file2 used for each line in file1
  tf <- file2$start >= file1$start[i] & file2$end <= file1$end[i]
  file1$mean[i] <- mean(file2$expr[tf])
  file1$sd[i] <- sd(file2$expr[tf])
}

write.csv(file1, file='result.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. That is exactly what I need. there is more thing needed to be updated when I run this code: tf<-c(file2$start>=file1$start[i]&file2$end<=file1$end[i]). I think it should be put into a vector, otherwise R will tell me tf is undefined.